# getting error in swat python lib while connecting AWS Lambda to SAS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sas

I am using AWS lambda layer with SWAT and other supported lib to run my lambda handler main script however it is failing in the beginning while connecting to CAS.

below is the error :

```
Could not get TK handle
[ERROR] SWATError: Could not create CAS error handler object. Check your SAS TK path setting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 83, in <module>
    conn = swat.CAS(bc.cas_host,bc.cas_port,bc.cas_username,cas_password)
  File "/opt/python/swat/cas/connection.py", line 402, in __init__
    raise SWATError('Could not create CAS error handler object. '
```

code used:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from base64 import b64decode
import swat
import requests
import json
import io
import boto3
import bc as bc
#print("tkpath:", swat.options.tkpath)
cas_password = bc.cas_password
conn = swat.CAS(bc.cas_host,bc.cas_port,bc.cas_username,cas_password)
```

can anyone please advise?

Comment: Did you check your tkpath setting?  Is it correct?

Comment: Also - have you considered connecting through the REST connection instead of the binary connection?  Might be easier.  I wonder if Lambda layer doesn't include the SAS TK libraries, in which case you'd have to go that route (see https://sassoftware.github.io/python-swat/sas-tk.html#sastk)